# Server Backup Solutions - compiling?

Tags: linux, backup

I've been researching backup solutions for a LAMP environment to backup our databases and files alike.  I'm looking for open source with a UI (so I'm less likely to screw it up).  I downloaded http://www.bacula.org/en/ and a few others but they all talk about compiling first.... this doesn't seem like something I should need to do.... is there a linux package that maybe handles backups that I don't know about?

I should also specify I'm looking to setup a backup server which backs up from several locations.

Comment: What linux distro are you using? There's almost certainly a command to just automatically install it; but they're different for various distros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ubuntu/debian:

```
apt-get install bacula
```

or, automysqlbackup, backup-manager, backupninja, cedar-backup, etc.

Play around with aptitude, type    /backup    and scroll through the list.  There are dozens of prepackaged backup solutions in Debian/Ubuntu.  I'm sure the same packaged versions are available for Fedora/CentOS, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Amanda](http://amanda.org) or it's commercial cousin Zmanda for your environment...

Comment: I looked at that... it asked me to compile it

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.